# How to query 3 tables in SQL?

Tags: sql

[image]

The question is :

4. The sales person gets a bonus pay if their amount exceeds a certain tier level for each year.

   Write a query that shows who would be getting a bonus and for how much.

So far I have

```
SELECT sum(t2.amount), t1.name,
FROM Salesperson t1
INNER JOIN Orders t2 on t1.ID = t2.salesperson_id
WHERE t2.amount >=
```

How can I satisfy the condition to compare the Amount according to the Bonus_pay table and also compare the year (Date)?

Comment: PLEASE do not add Image as data on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Your query needs a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query (Sql server) to get total amount per year for each sales person.

```
SELECT t1.Name, YEAR(t2.Order_date), SUM(Amount)
FROM Salesperson t1
INNER JOIN Orders t2 on t1.ID = t2.salesperson_id
GROUP BY t1.Name, YEAR(t2.Order_date)
```

To get their bonuses I will go with sub-queries. Maybe it can be more understandable for you.

```
SELECT T.Name, Bp.Year, SUM(Bp.Bonus) as BonusTotal
FROM (
    SELECT t1.Name, YEAR(t2.Order_date) as Year, SUM(Amount) as Total
    FROM Salesperson t1
    INNER JOIN Orders t2 on t1.ID = t2.salesperson_id
    GROUP BY t1.Name, YEAR(t2.Order_date)
) AS T
INNER JOIN Bonus_Pay Bp ON T.Year = Bp.Year AND T.Total >= Bp.Tier
GROUP BY T.Name, Bp.Year
```

As you have sale for each person per year, you can join to bonus_pay table by year and also select only tier where person can have some bonus.

P.S. Query was written without any check, maybe did some typo. So recommended to double-check it.

P.P.S I think it even can be optimised a bit to remove that sub-query

Comment: SELECT t.NAME,
       bp.year,
       Sum(bp.bonus) AS BonusTotal
FROM   (SELECT t1.NAME,
               Date_part('year', t2.order_date) AS year,
               Sum(amount) as Total
        FROM   salesperson t1
               INNER JOIN orders t2
                       ON t1.id = t2.salesperson_id
        GROUP  BY t1.NAME,
                  year) AS t
       INNER JOIN bonus_pay bp
               ON t.year = bp.year
                  AND t.total >= bp.tier
GROUP  BY t.NAME,
          bp.year 

i had to query getting year from date.

Comment: @julzoh to get only year from datetime value you can use `YEAR` function